# Boost Converter Gate Drive IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, boost, gate-driving

We are looking for a gate drive IC for a custom synchronous boost converter. The boost converter should cover a wide range of input and output voltages, for use with a solar cell to charge a battery. Therefore, for a first evaluation, the converter should be "discrete" and controlled by a microcontroller.

Now we could find on the search for a suitable IC mainly so-called "Synchronous Buck Converter Gate Driver" ICs. But none for "synchronous boost converter gate driver". Further there are half/full - bridge driver.

Why are there so many for "synchronous buck" and none for "synchronous boost" or is it possible to use a gate driver for a buck converter also for a boost converter? and if so what is there to consider in this case?

Comment: With external bootstrap voltage, the driver should not care if it drives a sync. boost or buck. Do you have any examples? Are you running with N or P FET?

Comment: What you're looking for is "bootstrap" drivers, which serve both sync buck/boost and half-bridge (and by extension full-) applications. There might be special-purpose drivers that include SR logic but you're more likely to find those under "sync. rect. controllers" or something like that.